# How to use Knex and rollup at the same time?

Tags: knex.js, rollupjs

I'm using rollup.js to build an app which depending Knex.js.
Knex support mysql, mssql, pgsql...
So there is code like `require('mysql')`, `require('tedious')`, `require('pg')` in Knex.js.

Finally, `require('mysql')`, `require('tedious')`, `require('pg')` show up in my output file.
But I have only used mysql.

reproduction:
https://github.com/daGaiGuanYu/temp/tree/knex-rollup